# How to prepend the contents of a .pri file with a path?

Tags: c++, qt, build, qmake

I have the fololowing directory structure and I would like to simplify things using the Qt .pri files.

```
Project1/
    project1.pro
    main.cpp
    Algorithms/
        algorithm1.h
        algorithm1.cpp
        ...
        // add an algorithms.pri file here
    Utilities/           
        utiliy1.h
        utiliy1.cpp
        ...
        // add an utilities.pri file here
    Gui/
        gui1.h
        gui1.cpp
        ...
        // add a gui.pri file here

AlgorithmsUnitTest/
     algorithms_unit_test.pro
     main.cpp

UtilitiesUnitTest/
     utilities_unit_test.pro
     main.cpp
```

One of the problems I am trying to solve is, that when I add or remove a source file from one of the `Algorithms`, `Utilities` or `Gui` folders, I have to remove it from all the other `.pro` files.

I would like to create a `.pri` file for each folder containing source and header files in that folder. These files would be included from all the other projects. Then if I add/remove a source or header file, I would remove it only from the corresponding `.pri` file.

The problem with this approach is that the inclusion of a `.pri` file in a `.pro` file is just a simple copy-paste. That is if `algorithms_unit_test.pro` included the `algorithms.pri` file, the qmake build system would look for the files in a nonexisting `AlgorithmsUnitTest/Algorithms` folder.

The solution would be to prepend the contents of the `.pri` file with

```
../Project1/
```

But I do not know how to do this. Please could you teach me how to do it or suggest some other way to organize my projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the qmake variable `PWD` in yours .pri files.

**algorithms.pri**

```
SOURCES      += $$PWD/algorithm1.cpp
HEADERS      += $$PWD/algorithm1.h
```

**utilities.pri**

```
SOURCES      += $$PWD/utiliy1.cpp
HEADERS      += $$PWD/utiliy1.h
```

...

http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qmake-variable-reference.html